# Getting unit to complete rotation before moving?

Tags: c#, unity, scripting, transformation, quaternion

I've been trying to get a unit in my project to move in a fashion similiar to that of modern MOBA games.

However, I am faced with the issue of the unit moving before the rotation is completed and the unit moving along the Y-axis.

I have tried using a cooroutine to allow the rotation to completed first, but to no avail.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour {

    public float smooth;
    public float speed;

    private float z;
    private float x;
    private Vector3 targetPosition;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {

            speed = 1;
            smooth = 20;

            RaycastHit hit;

            //var playerPlane = new Plane(Vector3.up, transform.position);
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            //double hitdist = 0.0;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                targetPosition = hit.point;

                x = hit.point.x;
                z = hit.point.z;
                //var targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetPoint    - transform.position);
                //transform.rotation = targetRotation;
            }   
        }


        StartCoroutine(Turn(x,z));

        //transform.position = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, speed*Time.deltaTime, 0.0f);
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, Time.deltaTime * smooth);
    }

    IEnumerator Turn(float _x, float _z)
    {
        Vector3 turn = new Vector3 (_x, 0, _z);
        transform.Rotate(turn, speed);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options here.

1. Moving the unit at the end of the coroutine (and maybe changing the name of the coroutine)
2. Creating a second coroutine that waits for the first one to finish before executing

Now I'll illustrate the examples

```
// 1st option
IEnumerator Turn(float _x, float _z)
{
    Vector3 turn = new Vector3 (_x, 0, _z);
    transform.Rotate(turn, speed);
    yield return null;
    // now move
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, Time.deltaTime * smooth);
}
```

Let's work out a second option with some code you commented, but I think it's a better approach

```
// Move function is the coroutine to be called to trigger movement
IEnumerator Move(Vector3 targetPosition)
{
    // we want to rotate first
    yield return Turn(Vector3 targetPosition);
    // then translate
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, Time.deltaTime * smooth);
}

IEnumerator Turn(Vector3 targetPosition)
{
    Quaternion srcRotation = transform.rotation;
    Quaternion dstRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetPosition);
    float percent = 0.1f;
    while (percent <= 1.0f)
    {
        Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(srcRotation, dstRotation, percent);
        transform.rotation = newRotation;
        percent += .01f;
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Using Lerp gives us smoothing and then you can change the values according to your own rotation speed, movement speed, etc.

Answer (score 1):

No need for the coroutine, just don't update the position until the rotation has been completed:

```
if(turnComplete){
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, Time.deltaTime * smooth);
}
```

Getting whether the turn is completed means checking how much more the unit needs to turn. If the remaining angle is small enough then `turnComplete=true;`